# RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout (Im using Fragments and a custom Adapter)

Tags: android

I am having trouble with RecyclerView and cuscom Apdapter and I don't know why. My code isn't throwing error when I'm building but a 
`E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`
 is showing at Run Logs.

I already watch a lot youtube tutorials and read other answers here at stockoverflow but still I am not able to fix my problem.

Here are my codes:

AccountFragment.java

```
public class AccountFragment extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: MY VARIABLES
    private RecyclerView listAccounts;
    private ArrayList<Account> arrayAccount = new ArrayList<>();
    private AdapterAccount adapterAccount;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutAccount;
    private Context context;
    private static final String accountURL = "LINK";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public AccountFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static AccountFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        AccountFragment fragment = new AccountFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    public void loadJSON(){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, accountURL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONArray accounts = new JSONArray(response);

                    for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject accountsObject = accounts.getJSONObject(i);

                        int id = accountsObject.optInt("accntID");
                        String username = accountsObject.optString("accntName");
                        String type = accountsObject.optString("accntType");
                        int station = accountsObject.optInt("statID");
                        String name = accountsObject.optString("lastName");
                        String address = accountsObject.optString("homeAddress");
                        String email = accountsObject.optString("emailAddress");
                        int contact = accountsObject.optInt("contactNumber");

                        Account account = new Account();
                        account.accountEntry(id, username, type, station, name, address, email, contact);

                        arrayAccount.add(account);
                    }

                    adapterAccount = new AdapterAccount(getContext());
                    listAccounts.setAdapter(adapterAccount);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity()).add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
        listAccounts = view.findViewById(R.id.accountRV);
        layoutAccount = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        listAccounts.setLayoutManager(layoutAccount);
        loadJSON();
        return view;
    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

AdapterAccount.java:

```
public class AdapterAccount extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterAccount.ViewHolderAdapterAccount> {

    private ArrayList<Account> arrayAccount = new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private Context context;

    public AdapterAccount(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public AdapterAccount(ArrayList<Account> arrayAccount) {
        this.arrayAccount = arrayAccount;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolderAdapterAccount onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolderAdapterAccount viewHolder = new ViewHolderAdapterAccount(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderAdapterAccount holder, int position) {
        Account currentAccount = arrayAccount.get(position);

        holder.accountID.setText(currentAccount.getId());
        holder.accountUsername.setText((currentAccount.getUsername()));
        holder.accountType.setText(currentAccount.getType());
        holder.accountStation.setText((currentAccount.getStation()));
        holder.accountName.setText(currentAccount.getName());
        holder.accountAddress.setText(currentAccount.getAddress());
        holder.accountEmail.setText((currentAccount.getEmail()));
        holder.accountContact.setText(currentAccount.getContact());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayAccount.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolderAdapterAccount extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView accountID;
        private TextView accountUsername;
        private TextView accountType;
        private TextView accountStation;
        private TextView accountName;
        private TextView accountAddress;
        private TextView accountEmail;
        private TextView accountContact;

        public ViewHolderAdapterAccount(View accountView) {

            super(accountView);

            accountID = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idPlaceXML);
            accountUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.usernamePlaceXML);
            accountType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.typePlaceXML);
            accountStation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stationPlaceXML);
            accountName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.namePlaceXML);
            accountAddress = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressPlaceXML);
            accountEmail = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.emailPlaceXML);
            accountContact = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contactPlaceXML);
        }
    }
}
```

Account.java:

```
public class Account {
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String type;
    private int station;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String email;
    private int contact;

    public void accountEntry(int id,String username,String type,int station,String name,String address,String email,int contact){
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.type = type;
        this.station = station;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.email = email;
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public int getStation() {
        return station;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 Things.1.try moving `adapterAccount = new AdapterAccount(getContext());      listAccounts.setAdapter(adapterAccount);` from `loadJSON()` to `onCreateView`. 2nd Set your `linearLayoutManager` like this `new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)` .HORIZONTAL is an example over here you can also keep it Vertical as well

Answer (score 0):

1. Add following method in `AdapterAccount`:

   ```
    public setAccountList(ArrayList<Account> arrayAccount) {
           this.arrayAccount = arrayAccount;
    }
   ```
2. Change `onCreateView`:

   ```
       @Override
       public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           // Inflate the layout for this fragment
           View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
           listAccounts = view.findViewById(R.id.accountRV);
           layoutAccount = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
           listAccounts.setLayoutManager(layoutAccount);
           adapterAccount = new AdapterAccount(getContext());
           listAccounts.setAdapter(adapterAccount);
           loadJSON();
           return view;
       }
   ```
3. Change `onResponse`

   ```
   public void onResponse(String response) {

           try {
              ...

               for (int i = 0; i < accounts.length(); i++) {
                  ...
                   arrayAccount.add(account);
               }
              adapterAccount.setAccountList(arrayAccount);
              adapterAccount.notifyDataSetChanged();
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }
   ```